# Laravel PHP Error 404 not found in laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-8

**in my code is**

[image]
then when I click to edit or delete, I found `404 not found` on my website
like this one
this is an error problem for me

[image]

and in code route

**web.php**

```
 Route::get('/rekaman/blog/edit/{$id}','BlogController@edit');

Route::get('/blog/{$id}/hapus','App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@destroy');
```

and then this my code for BlogController

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $artikel = Blog::find($id);
    return view('blog.blog_edit', ['artikel' => $artikel]);
}
public function destroy($id)
{
    $artikel = Blog::find($id);
    $artikel->delete();
    return redirect('/rekaman/blog')
    ->with('success','Artikel Anda Sudah Kami Hapus');
}
```

I hope you can help me
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Remove dollar sign from routing. So replace `{$id}` to `{id}`

```
Route::get('/rekaman/blog/edit/{id}','BlogController@edit');
Route::get('/blog/{id}/hapus','App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@destroy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `$` in your `$id`
e.g. `Route::get('/rekaman/blog/edit/{id}','BlogController@edit');`.

Then run `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your routes

```
Route::get('/rekaman/blog/edit/{id}','BlogController@edit');

Route::get('/blog/{id}/hapus','App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@destroy');
```

then run command  `php artisan optimize`

then you got your solution